# How can I allow controller access only for form submission?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have one controller in CodeIgniter. I didn't want to allow anyone to access controller. this controller can be accessed only for the form submission. How can I do it? below is given controller code.

```
    public function editad($uniqueid = ''){
        $this->load->model('Ads');
        $this->load->model('Postingad');
        $data = 
        if($uniqueid == ''){
           show_404();
        }
        $checkbox = $this->Ads->products($uniqueid);
        $product = json_decode($this->input->post('products'));
        $checked = $this->input->post('product_category');
        for($i = 0; $i < count($checkbox); $i++){
            $checkboxes[] = $checkbox[$i]['Product'];
        }
        for($i = 0; $i < count($checkbox); $i++){
            if(!in_array($checkbox[$i]['Product'], $product)){
                if($checkbox[$i]['Image'] != 'http://wallpapercraze.com/images/wallpapers/nowallpaper-585747.jpeg'){
                    unlink('./uploads/'.$checkbox[$i]['Image']);
                }
                $this->Ads->deletecheckbox($uniqueid,$checkbox[$i]['Product']);
            }
        }
        $files = array(
            'electronics'=>'efile',
            'kitchen'=>'kfile',
            'decoratives / Interior'=>'dfile',
            'Home Decor'=>'hdfile',
            'Furnitures'=>'ffile',
            'Toys'=>'tfile',
            'Vehicles'=>'vfile',
            'Other'=>'ofile'
        );
        $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/'.$uniqueid;
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $this->load->library("upload", $config);
        for($i = 0; $i < count($checked); $i++){
                $filenamefield = $files[$checked[$i]];
                if($_FILES[$filenamefield]['size'] > 0){
                    if($this->upload->do_upload($filenamefield)){
                        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                        $filename = $upload_data['file_name'];
                        $checkboxinfo = array(
                            'UniqueID'=>$uniqueid,
                            'Product'=>$checked[$i],
                            'Image'=>$uniqueid.'/'.$filename
                        );
                        $this->Postingad->checkbox($checkboxinfo);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    $checkboxinfo = array(
                        'UniqueID'=>$uniqueid,
                        'Product'=>$checked[$i],
                        'Image'=>'http://wallpapercraze.com/images/wallpapers/nowallpaper-585747.jpeg'
                    );
                    $this->Postingad->checkbox($checkboxinfo);
                }
        }
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($upload_data);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
```

Comment: Use CSFR token in form and check it at begginning of the method. If not valid redirect to other page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your function name with a `_`.

> In some cases you may want certain functions hidden from public access. To make a function private, simply add an underscore as the name prefix and it will not be served via a URL request.

Read more about this in this similair question: [CodeIgniter - Private functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266271/codeigniter-private-functions)

`public function editad($uniqueid = ''){` should be `public function _editad($uniqueid = ''){`

Comment: can you explain me with example? and thanks for your answer.

Comment: Changed my answer and added an example

Comment: Changing method visibility is better idea regarding PHP (CI included) standards. You can keep name starting underscore, but change visibility to `private` or `protected` and that method is not allowed from outside [child's] class.